# Firebase Performance: Retrofit network requests are not being logged

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, gradle, firebase-performance

Using

```
com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0
com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.4.0
com.google.firebase:firebase-perf-ktx (bom version is 29.0.4)
```

I'm unable to see any network requests inside the Firebase Performance network requests section. Custom traces work fine but the network requests are empty. I also cannot see any `I/FirebasePerformance` logcat logs suggesting that http requests are being logged.

The app uses a simple retrofit service to make requests which looks like:

```
    Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://myurl.com")
            .client(get())
            .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(get()))
            .build()
            .create(MyService::class.java)
```

The `OkHttpClient` :

```
    OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(UserAgentHeaderInterceptor())
            .addInterceptor(HttpLoggingInterceptor().apply {
                level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
            })
            .build()
```

I have already tried the following:

- Been through Firebase's trouble shooting [guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon/troubleshooting?platform=android#missing-network-request-data) for this issue.
- Downgraded my okHttp version to 3.12.